# What's the word(s) for a feeling of disappointment when you've lost something of financial value?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the word(s) for a feeling of disappointment when you've lost something of financial value? For example, let's say I'd just got an expensive LCD monitor from a raffle, but I accidentally dropped it and it broke, and I now lament its loss. I guess "lament" works okay, but it's not really a colloquial word, and it seems to refer to disappointment in a more general sense (like the loss of a good friend) rather than strictly about valuable possessions. The "value" in question should be strictly financial rather than emotional, meaning that you feel sorry for it being expensive rather than it having been used for a long time.

> I broke my brand-new LCD monitor. I haven't even gotten a single use out of it. I ... that monitor so much!

Edit: Just to drive home the point, there's this word in my language that is very specific, because it's used in contexts where you **miss out** on something of **monetary value**, **lose** something of **monetary value**. For example, when you almost won a monitor but didn't because of one stupid mistake on a game show; or when you'd just won a monitor, but accidentally damaged it and made it unusable; when you actually owned a monitor, but lost it while moving because the delivery guys dropped it. In all these cases, the disappointment is purely monetary, because the monitor was just too expensive and it'd be hard to ever get another one as good. Even in the case of you having owned the monitor, you still missed it because it was expensive, not because it was with you through thick and thin. As an actual example, I have this tablet that's quite cheap, but if I ever "miss" it, it's because of my emotional attachment to it, not because it's expensive, because it's actually very easily replaceable.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147056/discussion-on-question-by-vun-hugh-vaw-whats-the-words-for-a-feeling-of-disap); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you take an adjective instead of a verb? Try *bereft*:

> *I broke my brand-new LCD monitor. I haven’t even gotten a single use out of it. I am bereft.*

> **bereft**, *adj.*
> **1.** Forcibly deprived, robbed, having lost the possession or use *of*; void *of*.
>  <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

(*Bereft* can be used without *of* following it.)

Comment: I don't think this refers specifically to financial or monetary value, as the OP requested.

Comment: Where do you get your monitors for free? :-)   But you're right, **bereft** is indeed normally used figuratively, not literally.

Comment: @alphabet — I think $ when I think *robbed*.